# dafny corresponding SMT queries

Tags: dafny

I'm trying to inspect a simple looping program that **finds the maximal element in an integer array**. Here is the permalink [here](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/hrITU). Everything works fine, but I'm really interested in
the resulting SMT file, so I extracted it using:

```
$ dafny /compile:3 /proverLog:./mySMT.smt myCode.dfy
```

Then ran with `z3` as follows:

```
$ z3 ./mySMT.smt
```

I got 3 `unsat` responses and I was wondering **what are the corresponding 3 queries**?
I looked at the `*.smt` file and found 11K of machine-generated SMT.
Any tips on deciphering the smt file? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the resulting SMT file, then that 11K file is your answer. I imagine that looking at it will lead you to the conclusion that you don't actually want to look at the resulting SMT file.

So, I don't know what it is that you want to accomplish. If you want to learn more about your program, then the best way is to work (only) from the Dafny program text. For example, you can add more `assert` statements to, essentially, ask the verifier if the given condition is provable at the location of the statement.

If you're interested in how Dafny encodes its verification conditions (that is, if you yourself are a tool developer and want to learn how to generate good verification conditions), then I suggest you use the `/print` switch to generate the Boogie program that Dafny generates. With some understanding of the Boogie intermediate verification language, the Boogie code is readable. For a more tutorial account of how to encode a Dafny-like language into Boogie, I recommend:

> "Specification and verification of object-oriented software",
>   K. Rustan M. Leino.
>   Lecture note, Marktoberdorf 2008.

Rustan

PS. Unless you insist on particular formatting, you can print your array elements without using a loop if you first convert the array's element to a sequence:

```
print "a = ", a[..], "\n";
```